# How to allow WPF to resolve ContentTemplate for a Window control when using Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am trying to create a simple dialog-type control that is based on the WPF Window class (Popup won't do the trick here).
In my app I register a DataTemplate in Application.Resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:EntitySelectorViewModel}">
        <local:EntitySelector></local:EntitySelector>
    </DataTemplate>        
</Application.Resources>
```

In my Window control I set Window.Content and I expect WPF will set the ContentTemplate to an instance of EntitySelector based on the DataTemplate registration shown above:

```
[Export(typeof(EntitySelectorDialog))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class EntitySelectorDialog : Window
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public EntitySelectorDialog(EntitySelectorViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

           // DataContext = vm;  // does not work

           // EDIT: Per two answers shown below the following should work but it does not.
           Content = vm;  
    }
}
```

The problem is that WPF does not resolve the ContentTemplate i.e. an instance of EntitySelector is not created.  Furthermore, when I look at the XAML for EntitySelectorDialog I see that an instance of the shell has been injected 
into the Window control (EntitySelectorDialog).

I don't know enough about Prism to know if I want to go with the flow and use the shell somehow or if I want to prevent Prism from injecting it at all.  I don't think I have any need for it in this specific control so if it makes sense to just prevent Prism from injecting it I would prefer that route.

For the record I have tried removing the Prism attributes from my Window control and I new up the components manually.  That appears to have no effect - Prism still manages to somehow inject the shell and my ContentTemplate is not resolved.

There is no XAML to show for the Window control (EntitySelectorDialog) except the Window declaration itself - I want the content to come entirely from the ContentTemplate (EntitySelector).

I've looked at this which may provide an answer but I don't know how to implement it without breaking the rest of the app:

[Getting Unity to Resolve views in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735836/getting-unity-to-resolve-views-in-xaml)

Comment: What prevents you from using the `ViewModelLocator`? Why MEF - Unity or any other real DI container is better suited? What does the code look like that creates and shows the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Content` of the window to a `ContentControl` and set or bind the `Content` property of this one to the view model:

```
[Export(typeof(EntitySelectorDialog))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class EntitySelectorDialog : Window
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public EntitySelectorDialog(EntitySelectorViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
        Content = new ContentControl() { Content = vm };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think your answer is correct but it still does not work.

Comment: What happens? What do you see in the window?

Comment: I see nothing.  An instance of of the view (EntitySelector) is not created.

Comment: What if you set the Content to a TextBlock? Do you see it?

Comment: And you have confirmed that you are actually getting a EntitySelectorViewModel in the constructor of the window?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed.

Comment: What if you put some TextBlock in your DataTemplate. Are you seeing it? If you don't, you know that the template is not being applied. Try to define it in a ResourceDictionary that you merge into the window's Resources property.

Comment: Thanks for these troubleshooting steps!  I moved the data template to Window.Resources and it works.  It is interesting to note that other controls with DataTemplates defined in the same ResourceDictionary are working fine -however that is a subject for another question.  Please set your answer accordingly and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `vm` to `EntitySelectorDialog.Content` to trigger WPF solve the `DataTemplate` according to the type. So you either add

```
Content = vm;
```

in constructor or add

```
Content = {Bing}
```

in Xaml.

Comment: Thanks Alex - you are correct of course however for WPF is not cooperating.  It does not work.